# Add member to GitHub repo using CLI or REST

Tags: github, github-api

I have a private repo that belongs to my organization on GitHub. Is there any way to add members to this repo (or to a team) using GitHub CLI or any other API that allows me to perform this action programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add collaborator to rope by CLI:

```
# GitHub CLI api
# https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api

gh api \
  --method PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/collaborators/USERNAME \
  -f permission='triage'
```

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/collaborators?apiVersion=2022-11-28#add-a-repository-collaborator